# Can't move or arrange the tabs in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

For example I want to move the MainActivity code window/tab (highlighted in yellow in the screenshot below) to the left, but I when I drag and drop it goes back to being on the right. I can't move or arrange any number of open tabs.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I can drag and drop my tabs just fine, are you sure you're moving it all the way across?

Comment: Did you try to drag and drop the tab "activity_main.xml" all the way to the right also? Does that work?

Comment: Hey guys thank you for commenting, yeah I tried but it didn't work. As per the answer below I had "sort alphabetical" checked so they were locked to that order. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on `MainActivity.kt`, then select "configure editor tabs".

Make sure "sort tabs alphabetically" is unchecked.
Probably one of the checks there is in charge of your problem.

You can click on the top right "reset" there, it should solve your problem.

[image: Editor Tabs - screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Move with holding **ctrl** (or alt)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, although in my case the Sort tabs alphabetically option wasn't checked.
Since I wasn't able to solve this issue otherwise, I resorted to restoring the default setting i.e.

**File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings...**

which worked for me.